# android, adb, no such file or directory

Tags: permissions, storage, adb, chmod, ddms

I am having problems accessing the files I have created in my application.
Have went through all the possible suggestions in the internet and I still can't access the files.

- I am using rooted phone
- I am writing files to External Storage on Samsung Galaxy Nexus
- DDMS sees the created files but whenever I try to pull them it shows me:

> [2013-06-25 11:45:26 - ddms] transfer error: No such file or directory
>
> [2013-06-25 11:45:26] Failed to pull selection: No such file or directory

However, the files are visible in DDMS, and yes I have tried both selecting the phone, and the package in the Devices explorer on the left side

When I open the adb shell as a root:

> su
>
> cd storage/sdcard0

then I entered both

> chmod 777 myPackage

and

chmod -R 777 myPackage

but still it does not change the permissions for the files that I have written into this directory. Also chmod 777 directly on a file in a myPackage directory does not work and returns : No such a file or directory.

Needless to say that I cannot pull the files from above the shell.

Here's the code I'm using to generate the files.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

    ArrayList<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();

    String fileName;
    File file;
    File parameterFile;

    //generate data containing general information about the device
    //retrieve the data from the intent

    parameters=arg0.getStringArrayListExtra("com.example.mypackage.parameters");
    for(int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); ++i)
    {
        parameter = parameters.get(i);
        String[] split = parameter.split(" ");
        String name=split[1];
        fileName = name + ".csv";

        //check the state of the external storage
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Log.e("DIR: ", "STATE: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        //return info if the storage is read-only
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
        {Log.e("DIR: ", "STATE: READ_ONLY");}

        final File parametersDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("myPackage"), "Parameters");
        parametersDir.mkdirs();

        parameterFile = new File(parametersDir, fileName);
        parameterFile.setExecutable(true);
        generateTextFile(parameterFile, parameter);

        //check file's permissions
        parameterFile.setExecutable(true, false); 
        parameterFile.setReadable(true, false);
        parameterFile.setWritable(true, false);

        boolean executable = parameterFile.canExecute();
        boolean readable = parameterFile.canRead();
        boolean writable = parameterFile.canWrite();

        if(!executable){Log.e("FILE: ", "File cannnot be executed.");}
        if(!readable){Log.e("FILE: ", "File cannnot be read.");}
        if(!writable){Log.e("FILE: ", "File cannnot be written to.");}

        }
```

and here's the method I am using to generate the files

```
private void generateTextFile(File file, String string)
   {    
        try {                   
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            try{
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.append(string);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                String path = file.getPath();
                Log.e("Directory: ", path);

            } 

            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.e("FILE: ", "Cannot create filewriter. Writer problem.");
            }

            finally 
            {
                stream.getFD().sync();
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
            }

        }    
        catch(IOException e)

        {
            Log.e("FILE: ", "Cannot write to file. Stream problem.");
        }
   }
```

according to log, once my files are written, even though I am setting them to readable, writable and executable, their permissions are still unchanged

to clear the doubts, i also have declared in the manifest

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>
> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

I got to the point that I really have no idea what to do next, so I would be very glad if anyone could help.

Comment: Problem solved, this wasn't about permissions. Remember kids, make sure to remove end of the line character before extention when defining a file name!!